# Лишние отступы в IE

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

[image: IE11]

[image: Chrome]

Проблема,такая,как избавится от лишних отступов в IE11,и нормального отображение толщины текста?

```
.header {color: white;}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 1.2em "NexaHeavy", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 6.7em;
  padding: 1.2em 0;
  background-color: #f26c4f; }
  .logo .triangle-logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1.7em;
    left: 7.6em;
    border: 1.4em solid transparent;
    border-left: 1.4em solid #f26c4f; }

.main-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 1.8em "NexaRegular", sans-serif;
  padding-top: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 1em; }
```

Document

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1>g</h1>
        <div class="triangle-logo"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-title">
        <p>Good Inc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3 newsletter">
      <p>Newsletter</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear-block"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Телепатическую защёлку оставил на Криптоне. Где проблемный код-то?

Comment: А разметка? Желательно указать версию IE, с которой проблемы.